# How do you set a gCloud snapshot schedule so it appears in the GLOBAL list?

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-compute

When creating an "Instance Template," there is an option under "Boot Disk" > "Show Advanced Configuration" to add a snapshot schedule. When you click the dropdown, it shows "There are no schedules in GLOBAL."

How do you add a **GLOBAL Snapshot Schedule**? I have several Snapshot schedules that do not have a GLOBAL option to select, and none appear in the list.

[image: Instance Template - Snapshot Schedule selection]